# When my child_removed event is triggered, it also triggers my child_added. How can I avoid this?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Now I'm programming a webapp, with Firebase as a data store.

My question is about that. I set a query for `child_added` and `child_removed` perfect, my `child_removed` is triggered OK, when deleting a child, but when I delete a child, it also triggers my `child_added`. This is my code:

```
          db.ref('posts/').limitToLast(1).on('child_added',(snapshot,prevChildKey)=>{

            if(this.newPubsSearch){
                console.log(prevChildKey)
                this.newPubs= true
                console.log(snapshot)
                var pub = snapshot.val()
                pub['.key'] = snapshot.key

                this.pubstmp.unshift(pub)
            }
            this.newPubsSearch = true
        })

        db.ref('posts/').on('child_removed', function(snapshot){
            for(var pub in vm.pubs){
                if(vm.pubs[pub]['.key']==snapshot.key){
                    vm.pubs.splice(pub,1)
                    break
                }
            }
        })
```

Did it happen to someone else?
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

From how much i understand you code, You are getting a `child_added` event along with the `child_removed` event.

But this happens only when the `last item` is removed from the `posts`.

According to your code:

```
db.ref('posts/').limitToLast(1).on('child_added',(snapshot,prevChildKey)=>{...});
```

`child_added` will be triggered everytime new child gets added at the end of the `posts` i.e. the `last child` (because of limitToLast(1) ). So, whenever the last child of `posts` is removed, `second last child` becomes the `last child`, and firebase takes that as an addition of new child at the last. thus it triggers the `child_added` event.

For more information, please go through [Firebase limitToLast Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#limitToLast) ,  and read it throughly and carefully.